# returning bool from member variable pointer

Tags: c++

So I'm working with this code that looks like this:

```
class SomeClass : public SomeBaseClass {
    SomePointerToClass * p;
  public:
    SomeClass(SomePointerToClass* p = NULL) : p(p) {};
    void start(SomePointerToClass* sp) {
        p = sp;
    }
    bool hasStarted() {
        return p;
    }
}
```

I simplified some stuff so that I could make a short code example, but I think the returning a bool from a member variable pointer is a bit of a codesmell. Should I change it or is this some form of C++ convention?

Comment: **Moderator Note:** The migration rejection of this is being discuss on [Meta CR](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/what-about-this-so-question-renders-it-unsuitable-for-migration-to-cr).  Please move the discussion there.

Comment: Note that while this works in C++, in C if the pointer happens to end in 0x00, the method will erroneously return 0; unless the pointer is being used directly in the if/while condition, one should use `!= NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasStarted()` is fine: in C++, the pointer will be automatically converted to `bool` on a zero/not-zero basis.<sup>†</sup>

Some people prefer to write `return (p != nullptr)` or `return static_cast<bool>(p)` instead, in order to be really explicit about intent, but I'm not terribly fussy about that in cases like this.

<sub><sup>†</sup> However, the behaviour is implementation-defined in C, so do *not* rely on it there!</sub>

Comment: I didn't include the constructor, but it basically takes a default parameter SomeClass(SomePointerToClass * p = NULL). I was just wondering why hasStarted() didn't it return something like p != NULL;

Comment: @AndresBucci: You must always post [_complete_ testcases](http://sscce.org) here, please.

Comment: @AndresBucci: The pointer will be automatically converted to `bool` on a zero/not-zero basis.

Comment: Thanks. I guessed it converted it to bool doing this, I just didn't know if it was a good way of doing so.

Comment: @Kevin: (1) As I said in my answer and comment, there is an automatic (read: implicit) conversion between pointers and booleans.

Comment: @Kevin: (2) Pointers are scalar types (`[C99: 6.2.5/21]`) and, as such, conversion to `_Bool` is defined for those types (`[C99: 6.3.1.2/1]`); however, this relies on a pointer-to-integer conversion which is implementation-defined (`[C99: 6.3.2.3/6]`). Therefore, yes, in C I would probably avoid this shorthand.

Comment: @Kevin: No need to "try C++"; I guarantee you that the conversion is well-defined, and has been for decades (`[C++11: 4.12/1]`, et al). This will be covered in any good introductory C++ book.

Comment: OK, that's why I said "not sure about c++"

Comment: @Kevin: Well, I _am_ ;) BTW I frickin' love SFF.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool hasStarted () { return (bool) p; }
```

This makes it clear "I meant to do that," and is, I'd say, a very reasonable thing to do.

I sometimes do this inside a function that has access to a pointer p:

```
if (p) ... //meaning:  if p isn't NULL...
```

but the consensus is I shouldn't mention *returning* a pointer -- and I'm sure the consensus is correct here.  So edited.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that suggestion. The OP clearly doesn't want to actually expose the pointer, so whether it's meant to be "kept private" or not, your function no longer has the _meaning_ that it did before: you're no longer encapsulating the logic that decides whether the object "has started".

Comment: You must mean the latter part.  I'd agree:  it's better not to expose the pointer, but to cast it to bool.

Comment: Exposing the pointer is a bad idea. It doesn't seem like much, and it seems to provide more abilities for client code (like "check the pointer value", "store the pointer & use it later" and so on). This in turn will allow client code to be written, that makes you realize a year or so later, that your `myPtr` function fulfills a contract that is not documented anywhere and really bad for maintenance (such as `SomeClass` MUST be implemented in terms of a `SomePointerToClass` instance and MUST expose it's address"), because someone wrote lots of client code that assumed so.

Comment: Are you sure it's always evil?  const char* c_str() const; returns a pointer.  How else could -- or should -- you write c_str?

Comment: But I edited my answer anyway, to reflect the reservations expressed here.